# Can't make Wiegand RFID-reader and Odroid C2 work properly

Tags: serial, uart, rfid

I've got one pretty interesting task. The task is the following:
Odroid C2 (Single board computer) running on Android 5.1 has to recieve card id from [RFID-reader](http://www.globalsources.com/gsol/I/RFID-reader/p/sm/1153822871.htm#1153822871) over `Wiegand` interface.
To accomplish this my app listens to `UART` port (/dev/ttyS1) with `SU` permission:

```
public SerialPort(...){
    Process su = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/system/bin/su");
    String cmd = "chmod 666 " + "path/to/the/device" + "\n"
                    + "exit\n";
    su.getOutputStream().write(cmd.getBytes());
    ...
}
```

and `tty` configuration in `JNI` as follows:

```
JNIEXPORT jobject JNICALL Java_android_1serialport_1api_SerialPort_open(...) {
    int fd;
    speed_t speed;
    jobject mFileDescriptor;

        /* Opening device */
    {
        fd = open("path/to/the/device", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY);  
    }
        //all check blocks are omitted for the sake of simplicity

        /* Configure device */
    {
        struct termios cfg;

        cfsetospeed(&cfg, speed);
        cfsetispeed(&cfg, speed);

        cfg.c_cflag |= (CLOCAL | CREAD);     //ignore modem controls
        cfg.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE;
        cfg.c_cflag |= CS8;          //8-bit characters
        cfg.c_cflag &= ~PARENB;      //no parity bit
        cfg.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;      //only need 1 stop bit
        cfg.c_cflag &= ~CRTSCTS;     //no hardware flowcontrol

        //setup for non-canonical mode
        cfg.c_iflag &= ~(IGNBRK | BRKINT | PARMRK | ISTRIP | INLCR | IGNCR
        | ICRNL | IXON);
        cfg.c_lflag &= ~(ECHO | ECHONL | ICANON | ISIG | IEXTEN);
        cfg.c_oflag &= ~OPOST;

        //fetch bytes as they become available
        cfg.c_cc[VMIN] = 1;
        cfg.c_cc[VTIME] = 0;

        //creating FileDescriptor...

        return mFileDescriptor;
    }
```

Lets move on to the `Java` side...Here we simply pass corresponding `FileDescriptor` as argument to the `FileInputStream` object to read from it later

```
public SerialPort(...){
    ...
    FileInputStream mFileInputStream;
    FileDescriptor mFd;

    mFd = open(...); //recieve newly created FileDescriptor

    mFileInputStream = new FileInputStream(mFd); //pass it as argument to FileInputStream
    ...
}
```

I read data from `FileInputStream` in another class with separate thread. And here is where my problem comes out.
Whenever I place rfid card in front of the reader `read()` function gets triggered 15 times with `hex_val` equal to `FC` (Dec = 252).

```
public FooClass(...){
    ...
    byte[] buffer = new byte[64];

    int size = mInputStream.read(buffer);
    if (size > 0) {

        for (int j = 0; j < buffer.length; j++) {
            String val = String.format("%02X ", buffer[j]);
            Log.v("hex_val", val);
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Searching through the internet I stumbled across one page

https://www.pololu.com/docs/0J9/3.c.07

mentioning this value as an error byte.

I will be infinitely grateful for any suggestion or concreate answers to the questions below:

- Is my `UART` configuration appropriate, or not? Should it be specific for a `Wiegand` protocol?
- Why do I recieve 15 bytes as opposed to 3Bytes (W26) or 4Bytes (W34)?

P.S. If you have working `Java` or `C` sketch, please leave it here, thank you.

Comment: It's all in the line signaling. wiegand and uart are fundamentally different.  it's possible with simple circuitry to convert wiegand to byte-per-bit uart data. (so you'd receive 34 or 26 bytes and then have to convet that to bits in software)

Comment: Hi, Jasen! Thanks for reply. What do you mean by "circuitry"?
 Could you give more elaborate explanation, or provide me with a link to look up in?

Comment: you've got two different inputs data0 and data1, you need to convert those into signals that your UART can handle, perhaps convert a pulse on data 1 into a long pulse on the UART input and a pulse on data0 into a short pulse. (all these signals are idle high, so "pulses" above are dips in voltage)  "long" should be 6 to 9 bit times, and "short"  1 to 4 then just look at 4th bit of the received character to determine weigand 1 or 0.  I did this for RS232 instead of UART (and posted it somewhere) so if you find it my circuit has the wrong voltages on the output.